# How to handle over-injection in React components

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I've found it very typical to have a large hierarchy of React components that each have their own dependencies passed down the line as props.

Due to these dependencies, the higher level components typically require a massive number of props to be supplied to them:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react');
var ComponentB = require('./ComponentB');
var ComponentC = require('./ComponentC');

class ComponentA extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ComponentB
                    dependencyA={this.props.dependencyA}
                    dependencyB={this.props.dependencyB}
                    dependencyC={this.props.dependencyC}
                    .../>

                <ComponentC
                    dependencyD={this.props.dependencyD}
                    dependencyE={this.props.dependencyE}
                    dependencyF={this.props.dependencyF}
                    .../>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ComponentA.propTypes = {
    dependencyA: React.PropTypes.object,
    dependencyB: React.PropTypes.object,
    dependencyC: React.PropTypes.object,
    dependencyD: React.PropTypes.object,
    dependencyE: React.PropTypes.object,
    dependencyF: React.PropTypes.object,
    //... x10
};

module.exports = ComponentA;
```

Now that I'm using Redux, this issue has been further exacerbated. Any global state or actionCreators used in the hierarchy must be passed down.

In backend-world, constructor over-injection is a sign that the Single Responsibility Principal is being violated. This is typically fixed by [refactoring to aggregating services](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/). In React-world, this doesn't resolve the issue as any aggregate components still need their dependencies passed down the hierarchy. In any case, I'm not convinced that SRP makes sense in a presentational context.

I perceive one of the issues to be the requirement to pass down actionCreators from the Container.

```
'use strict';

var { bindActionCreators } = require('redux');
var { connect } = require('react-redux');
var { dependencyC, dependencyD, dependencyE, ... } = require('../actions');
var ComponentA = require('../components/ComponentA');

// I understand why this is important
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        dependencyA: state.dependencyA,
        dependencyB: state.dependencyB
    };
}

// ... but not why this is important
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return Object.assign({}, bindActionCreators({ dependencyC, dependencyD, dependencyE, ... }, dispatch), { dispatch });
}

module.exports = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ComponentA);
```

Why can't these just be added via require? I understand why it's important to pass state around via props - this state changes and should cause the component to be re-rendered. Functions passed as props seem like they would *very* rarely be changed dynamically.

Yes I know about `{...this.props}` but I dislike the fact that I'm passing dependencies in to a component that doesn't need it. Perhaps I just need to get over this but I wanted to check first that this was common and best practice.

**Is there anything that can be done to avoid over-injection with React components?**

Comment: You don't need to be using `bindActionCreators` in that instance. `ComponentA` is passed a `dispatch` function as a prop because it's being passed to `connect`. `ComponentA` can call `this.props.dispatch(dependencyC())`, `this.props.dispatch(dependencyD())`.

Comment: For your first code example, [Context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) might be what you're looking for. The note "Why Not To Use Context" is worth examining before starting to use it a lot though.

Comment: @RossAllen - ahh that's perfect - well at least for half the props! Thanks heaps!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using react's context to allow rendering of a child component into a parent/grandparent/great-grandparent.... Anti-pattern?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36358671/using-reacts-context-to-allow-rendering-of-a-child-component-into-a-parent-gran)